# Remap Ctrl + k to use Slack's quickfinder instead of Firefox's search page

Tags: firefox, shortcut-keys

The shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>k</kbd> maps to new search tab in Firefox, as well as quick finder in Slack. For whatever reason Firefox takes precedent. How can I ensure slack's shortcut is the one that fires?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to your Slack preferences, choose advanced, and click the thing that says ctrl k to quick switcher (overrides some browser behavior)

: )

Comment: Even with this setting enabled in Slack, on Firefox quantum (57+ I think), the browsers intercepts the keyboard shortcut most of the time for me. Occasionally it opens the quick switcher, but usually focuses the search box in Firefox